# A Button on a sidebar project to include a line on a spreadsheet is not working

Tags: google-apps-script

I´m creating a SideBar project, following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZNPkcT4PKA&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemuzTNWeHd8HziGVNzSlWACh&index=3

With all the code baked, my button doesn´t work.
I´ve triple checked evertything but don´t find any. Don´t know if it´s a concept or sintax error.
Included Bootstrap V.4.1.3 as the one followed by the tutorial.

uform.html

```
!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <!-- Required meta tags -->
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
   crossorigin="anonymous">
   <title>My SideBar</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
          <div class="mb-3">
             <label for="nombre-cliente" class="form-label">Cliente</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre-cliente">
         </div>
         <div class="mb-3">
             <label for="nombre-proyecto" class="form-label">Proyecto</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre-proyecto">
         </div>
        <button  class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton">Submit</button>
   </div>
         <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
         <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
         q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" 
         integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" 
         crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script>
        fuction afterButtonClicked(){
          var Cliente = document.getElementByID("nombre-cliente");
          var Proyecto= document.getElementByID("nombre-proyecto"); 
          var rowData = {Cliente:Cliente.value, Proyecto:Proyecto.value};
          google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData);
        }
      document.getElementByID("mainButton").addEventListener("click",afterButtonClicked);
    </script>; 
</body>
</html>
```

Tutorial recomends split on two code files,

first file is uformcode.gs

```
function loadUform() {
    const htmlForSidebar = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("uform");
    const htmlOutput = htmlForSidebar.evaluate();
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.showSidebar(htmlOutput); 
}
function createMenu() {
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    const menu = ui.createMenu("MyScripts"); 
    menu.addItem("FirstSript","loadUform");
    menu.addToUi();
}
function onOpen(){
    createMenu();
}
```

second file is funcs.gs

```
function addNewRow(rowData) {
   const currentDate = new Date(); 
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
   const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1"); /// ***here my sheet name*** 
   Logger.log(rowData)
   ws.appendRow([rowData.Cliente,rowData.Proyecto,currentDate]);
}
    /* This one passes this object as input to addNewRow, considering that rowData has two 
    attributes, Cliente and Proyecto, and giving it this two values. 
    This works (I execute it and the row gets into the sheet*/
function anotherFunc(){
    addNewRow({Cliente: "iPhone", Proyecto: 435});
}
```

Don´t know what happens, but every time we push the button seems like it´s dead.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many typos in the html file : `fuction` should be `function` . `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>My SideBar</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="nombre-cliente" class="form-label">Cliente</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre-cliente">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="nombre-proyecto" class="form-label">Proyecto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre-proyecto">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="mainButton">Submit</button>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-
         q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function afterButtonClicked() {
        var Cliente = document.getElementById("nombre-cliente");
        var Proyecto = document.getElementById("nombre-proyecto");
        var rowData = {Cliente: Cliente.value, Proyecto: Proyecto.value};
        google.script.run.addNewRow(rowData);
    }

    document.getElementById("mainButton").addEventListener("click", afterButtonClicked);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Little bit newbie writting clean code. 
I´m still not sure if just was what you pointed... changed one "fuction" and three "getElmentByID" but mine still didn´t worked... copied yours and gone smooth... could it be anything else you changed in yours and Í didn´t find? Thanks again.

Comment: should be just those apart from other small errors which should not affect that. You can use a diff tool to compare the 2 if you're interested in investigating further